# is there a loop in matlab similar to (for in ) in R?

Tags: r, matlab

In R if I have a index=[1,5,10];
I could use for i  in index to get each element of this vector: i=1, i=5, i=10 for each iteration.

I do not want to go through the size say

```
for i = 1:3
index(i)
end
```

Is there a similar way in matlab?

Comment: click the the left check mark to close this question if you're satisfied with the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can simply write

```
for i=[1 5 10]
    do something with i here
end;
```

for example

```
for i=[1 5 10]
    i
end;
```

will print

```
1
5
10
```

on the console.

Comment: Can we say for i = index end?

Comment: Yes, but it will simply loop through `index` without doing anything, so you get an empty loop that repeats `n` times, where `n` is the length of `index`.

Answer (score 0):

yes. You can simply run through the variable index. Here is an example.

```
for i= 1:max(size(index))
  do_something(index(i)); // e.g. print, multiply...

end
```

hope that helps

Comment: I mean could we loop just for the index like foreach?in R for i in index rather than loop through the size?

Comment: Its looping through the number of elements in index. So if do_something was the print function you would see "1, 5, 10" as your output. If you have a specific task that prevents you from doing it this way please explain and I can make an alternate suggestion.